# Simple jQuery validation plugin issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am having trouble getting a simple jQuery validation example to work.  How would this fiddle be modified to make the fields validate when they lose focus?

http://jsfiddle.net/jeljeljel/wyB3w/2/

**HTML**

```
<div id="pseudoForm">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" />
    <input type="text" name="last_name" />
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("#pseudoForm").validate({
    onfocusout: true,
    rules: {
        first_name: "required",
        last_name: "required"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seem to be many things wrong with your script+markup,

1. The input elements have got to be inside a form.
2. The input elements got to have an `id` to work with your code (*it has been brought to my attention, by respected fellow; Sparky, that this is not a requirement*)
3. as mentioned already, you're missing a `}`
4. jQuery validate works on forms
5. `onfocusout` can [either be `false` or a `function(){}`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions)

**[check this jsfiddle, contains corrected code](http://jsfiddle.net/wyB3w/4/)**

Correct HTML IMO

```
<form id="pseudoForm" >
    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" />
    <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" />
</form>
```

Correct Javascript

```
$("#pseudoForm").validate({
    onfocusout: function(fld){$(fld).valid()},
    rules: {
        first_name: 'required',
        last_name: 'required'
    }
});
```

Then you've got to find some way of posting form with a mouse :D but that isn't necessary for validate to work

Comment: Item #2 is false.  You do not need an `id`... you only need a `name`.

Comment: Item #1 and Item #4 are the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out about #2, I will correct it momentarily. For #1 and #4 being the same, you're not right. Imagine a situation when one is applying validate plugin on a form but doesn't put elements inside a form.

Comment: If I'm not correct about item 1 and 4 being the same issue, then that's an issue of a poorly worded answer.  The example in your comment makes no sense either... why would one apply the validate plugin to a form with no input elements?  In other words, if the plugin only works on forms, then naturally the input elements would have to be inside of a form.

Comment: spraky, we're trying to solve problems, because people make mistakes. If we expect everything to be _naturally correct_ then there should be no SO! `why would one apply the validate plugin to a form with no input elements`, answer is, "mistakenly". `The example in your comment makes no sense either` then the OP too should make absolutely no sense to you because he's not applying the plugin in right way. So your answer should have been "OP! You make no sense to me. Period" instead of the 1) 2) 3) boilerplate

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing `}` for the `rules` object.

Comment: Thanks, good catch. I fixed the fiddle and updated the link.  Same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Since your latest edits, I only see three issues:

**1**)  `onfocusout` can only be `false` or a function.  Setting it to true will break the plugin.  By default the plugin's `onfocusout` validation is only activated after the initial submit.  So I simply modified the default callback function so that it validates immediately.

**2**)  You can only use this plugin on `form` elements.

**3**)  Enclose `.validate()` within a DOM ready handler.

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/cKeeN/**

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#pseudoForm").validate({
        onfocusout: function (element, event) {
            this.element(element);
        },
        rules: {
            first_name: "required",
            last_name: "required"
        }
    });

});
```

**HTML**:

```
<form id="pseudoForm">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" />
    <input type="text" name="last_name" />
</form>
```

Comment: `plugin's onfocusout validation is only activated after the initial submit. ` then it is no longer a "onfocusout" validation, it's a _nosubmitvalidation_ if I'm to name it :). `3) Enclose .validate() within a DOM ready handler` OP is already aware of this requirement as he has "onload" selected in the fiddle.

Comment: @Ejay, if you have a problem with how this plugin operates and the terminology he chose, take it up with the developer.

Comment: @Ejay, you better check the page source code of the jsFiddle again.  `$(window).load(function(){` (onLoad fiddle option) is not the same as `$(function(){` (onDomready fiddle option).

Comment: No thanks, I'm not interested in jsfiddle sourcecode, I've other stuff to do :) I'm trying to say that, let me copy paste it, "OP is already aware of this requirement". thanks :)

Comment: @Ejay, you said the OP is aware of the DOM ready requirement because he used `onload` in the jsFiddle.  This is an incorrect assumption since the `onload` option is **not** the same as a `DOM ready` handler.  This fine distinction is very important to know, busy or not.

Comment: Sparky you're reading me wrong. "OP is already aware of this requirement" doesn't include any of the domready or window.load thing. I'm merely stating that OP knows about such requirement that's why you see one of them in the fiddle where it could be `No wrap - in <head>` or any other invalid option. I know domready and window.load are not same. I know `$(document).ready(...)` fires before `$(window).load(...)` but both of them ensure that the HTML has loaded, and **that** is what's needed by the plugin.

Comment: @Ejay, I think you misunderstood me too... `onLoad` is simply the **default option** in any jsFiddle, so this does not necessarily mean the OP made the selection or is aware of any such requirement.  He does not have a DOM ready handler in his original question either, so it's very much worth mentioning.

Comment: I hear you brother :) `so this does not necessarily mean` this is different from person to person. The code in OP's question doesn't necessarily mean that he's using even a `<script>` tag. I know it's not very bright assumption, but just for sake of _so this does not necessarily mean_

Comment: Ok i'm going to delete this all, yet agian, useless discussion. What do you say? I can delete my answer too if you like.